# Making an old library work with Perl XS and PerlIO

Tags: perl, xs, perl-io

I am rather an XS beginner and I am looking into changing an existing XS module which uses a  15+ year old underlying C library heavily (in fact the module is basically just glue to this library). The problem is that I would like to be able to use PerlIO string trickery like:

```
open($fh, '<', \$string);
```

and then pass `$fh` to the XS glue where the library is expecting `FILE`. The problem is that the XS has:

```
int
_parse (entry_ref, filename, file, preserve=FALSE)
    SV *    entry_ref;
    char *  filename;
    FILE *  file;
    boolean preserve;
```

and I assume that it needs to be:

```
PerlIO *  file;
```

This doesn't work of course as there must be more to it than that. When I look at the `_parse` code in the library, it ends up in:

```
AST * bt_parse_entry (FILE *    infile,
                      char *    filename,
                      btshort    options,
                      boolean * status)
{
   AST *         entry_ast = NULL;
   static int *  err_counts = NULL;
   static FILE * prev_file = NULL;
```

with `FILE` types again. Now the basic question I have have to start with is - is this even possible without changing the library; that is, can I get pseudo-filehandle from strings PerlIO behaviour just by changing the XS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Perl API provides [`PerlIO_exportFILE()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlapio.html#*PerlIO_exportFILE(f%2cmode)*) ([Implementation](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/v5.18.0/perlio.c#L3727)) which can convert a PerlIO handle with a file descriptor to a stdio `FILE` pointer. Since [PerlIO::Scalar](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/v5.18.0/ext/PerlIO-scalar/scalar.pm) is an "in-memory" file handle without a file descriptor the conversion cannot succeed. The only portable way to pass a `PerlIO::Scalar` handle would be to flush it to a temporary file. The less portable way would be to use a stdio that supports callbacks, like the BSD implementation, [funopen(3)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=funopen&sektion=3).